# Does Human Activity Impact No Man's Sky Economy?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've recently been playing the new pathfinder update and realized that many buyers in the same star system have similar pricing.

How does the economy work in this game?  Do other players in my local star system impact the economy at all? Are prices based on the resources available in the local star system?

For ex, player 1 sells 1 million iron units one warp drive away from player 2's current star. Would this impact iron pricing in player 2's star system that is in the same local star system?

Answer (score 1):

Unless its changed since last I checked, No Man's Sky has no multiplayer components whatesoever. Based on some of the things I've read on the game, it appears that prices aren't based on what the system has an abundance of.

Comment: I think when the OP says "other players", they mean if someone else visits the star system that they are in/were in in their version of the game.  I.E. will player ones choices impact the pricing set in players twos version of the game?

Comment: Local region seems to imply actual location as apposed to an ingame star system. @TimmyJim

Comment: @TimmyJim - I've edited for clarity. The question is strictly in-game.  I can't imagine European player transactions being cause for impact on a NA player's economy.

Comment: "Unless its changed since last i checked..." It has. While there is no real-time multiplayer (thankfully), one player can occupy the base of another, one player can leave messages for others to discover, and similar asynchronous multiplayer interactions are possible.